# DB2 - Open next cursor if first cursor returns nothing

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

What I'm trying to do:

I have two cursors in a DB2 stored procedure. I would like to run the first, if it returns an empty result set, then I would like to run the next cursor. What is the syntax for achieving this? Can I evaluate results for a cursor before opening it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue with opening the cursor and checking for results?  I'm not a fan of using them, but being able to do such logic is one of their advantages.  If you post the queries, then perhaps others can figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: No, you can't evaluate whether or not a statement will return rows until you actually run it.  If there are no rows returned, you get back `SQLCODE = 100`.  The optimizer can _guess_ the probability of results, but you don't usually have access to stuff that low level during normal use.  As @Gordon says, post the queries, maybe something better can be written.

Answer (score 1):

The [DB2 SQL Cookbook](http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html) has lots of helpful examples, including use of cursors and error handling. As far as testing for output is concerned, you may have an easier time surrounding the cursor with an `IF EXISTS()` test that runs the same query as the cursor.